# Is there anything wrong with having a Bayesian logistic regression model with beta priors?

Tags: logistic, bayesian, beta-distribution, jags

The Bayesian logistic regression model with beta priors seem to work using JAGS. I just can't find any examples of it in any literature or any tutorials. They all seem to use normal priors.

Just want to know there are any issues.

Model in JAGS (I have just changed a dnorm model to a dbeta one and I have put in uninformed priors):

```
model {
  for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
    # In JAGS, ilogit is logistic:
    y[i] ~ dbern( ilogit( zbeta0 + sum( zbeta[1:Nx] * zx[i,1:Nx] ) ) )
  }
  # Priors vague on standardised scale:
  zbeta0 ~ dbeta(1,1)
  for ( j in 1:Nx ) {
    zbeta[j] ~ dbeta(1,1)
  }
  # Transform to original scale:
  beta[1:Nx] <- zbeta[1:Nx] / xsd[1:Nx]
  beta0 <- zbeta0 - sum( zbeta[1:Nx] * xm[1:Nx] / xsd[1:Nx] )

  # Compute predictions at every step of the MCMC
  for ( k in 1:Npred){
    pred[k] <- ilogit(beta0 + beta[1] * xPred[k,1] + beta[2] * xPred[k,2] + beta[3] * xPred[k,3] + beta[4] * xPred[k,4])
  }
}
```

There are four variables - they are proportions in the domain [0,1] that try to predict a binary indicator.

Comment: Priors on the usual logistic coefficients? How do you know they are restricted to $[0,1]$?

Comment: I am using priors that are proportions (e.g. proportion of the population that is employed, proportion that lived at the same address five years ago) to classify regions in to urban and regional.

Comment: What about that fact makes you think that the regression coefficients have to be restricted to $[0,1]$?

Comment: They are all proportions and are restricted to [0,1]. Are you saying that even though the priors are restricted, the coefficients don't have to be restricted?

Comment: I get that you have proportion data. Why do your coefficients have to be proportions? Why not double the log-odds?

Comment: I get what you are saying. I'm new to Bayesian statistics though. How would you implement that in a model?

Comment: How would I implement what? By doubling the log-odds, I mean that the coefficient is $2$, which is not a matter of being Bayesian.

Comment: Can you explain to us your model, with formulas?

Comment: Thanks. I have added more details.